# Joining files on disk

Tags: files, text-processing, zsh

Say I have several file with the following naming:

```
000001
000002
000003
...
```

Each of these files is a `csv` file (may include escape characters). In total the folder has `~20GB` of data. How can I stitch these files together into a single final file?

In case it matters I usually use `Zsh`.

Comment: Is order of content in final file preserve, meaning content of file1 then content of file2...

Comment: @Gnouc - Yes. We want to preserve ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cat <->.csv > all.csv
```

Where `<->` matches any positive integer decimal number, will concatenate all those (in lexical order, which for 0 padded numbers is the same as numerical order) into `all.csv`.

That will double the space on disk though. If you don't intend to keep the original files, you could do:

```
for i in <->.csv; do
  cat $i && rm -f $i || break
done > all.csv
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting `zsh: no matches found: <->.csv` with the first solution.

Comment: @user815423426, `<->.csv` matches the files that are named like `0000001.csv` (or `any-positive-decimal-integer-number.csv` as I said). If they're called 000001, replace it with `<->`.

Comment: Oh man. I can't believe I missed that.. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you use redirection, that will either append or overwrite contents to one file. If you want to append to one file, use:

`cat file.csv file2.csv file3.csv >> all.csv`

This next command will overwrite to all.csv:

`cat file.csv file2.csv file3.csv > all.csv`

But say you want to move all CSV files to one csv in a given directory (to append to):

`cat *.csv >> all.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to combine all those files into one file?

1. If you want to feed them to a program that wants stdin, you can do this:

   ```
   cat *.csv | prog
   ```

   or any of the other combination methods mentioned earlier.
2. If the program expects a named file as input, do something like this:

   ```
   mkfifo p
   cat *.csv > p &
   prog p
   ```
3. If you want one file because one file is easier to backup, then tarring everything together can be useful.  If you want to read the files w/o untarring them, then you can turn the tar file into a fuse-based fs.